# Chlidren should force parent to increase its width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's simple example of what I'm trying to achieve. Children are contained inside a parent container and parent container shouldn't shrink less than necessary to contain all children, instead it should stay big enough. Now it shrinks to the viewport width and if user scrolls, he can see other items but parent looks weird.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: I converted it into a running snippet. Click "expand snippet" and shrink browser window a bit, so all items won't fit into width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you could use `inline-flex` on `container`.

The reason why `display: flex` won't work is that it behave like a block element, and as such it won't be wider than its parent, in this case the `body`, but an inline element grows with its content.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to make the `container`'s parent a flex container, in this case by adding `display: flex` to the `body`, and with that the `container` will also be a flex item, and as such won't shrink below its content.

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `flex: 1 1 0;` to `.item` class.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parents no longer show, now your problem is making the space between the item.

**Here's working snippet that parents follow children's Height**

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: blue;
    }


    .item {
          flex: 1;
          padding: 10px;  
          background-color: red;
          font-size: 50px;
          position:relative;
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

Remove the `margin-right:5px;` if you don't want any space between items.